# If $ 3a+2b+c=7$ then find minimum value of $ a^2+b^2+c^2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, optimization, maxima-minima, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

**Question:- If $ 3a+2b+c=7$ then find the minimum value of $ a^2+b^2+c^2 $.**

I used vectors to solve this problem.

Let $$α=3\hat{i}+2\hat{j}+\hat{k}$$
$$β=a\hat{i}+b\hat{j}+c\hat{k}$$

Using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality

we have, $|α.β|\le |α| |β|$

$=|3a+2b+c|\le\sqrt{14}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

$= 7\le\sqrt{14}\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$

So, $a^2+b^2+c^2\ge \frac72$

Therefore, the minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$ is $\frac72$

I want to know are there any other method to find the minimum value of
$a^2+b^2+c^2$ such as using inequalities and calculus by assuming function $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2$.

Comment: Lagrange multiplies work well here.

Comment: Sorry, typo.  "Lagrange multipliers".

Comment: Essentially you want the distance from the origin to the plane $3x+2y+z = 7$. You can find this by easily by considering the line perpendicular to that plane passing through the origin and finding the point of intersection of that line and the plane.

Comment: @RohanNuckchady, I either missed your comment or I was composing my answer when you posted it.

Comment: @BarryCipra I did not see your answer when I commented this! We were probably typing at the same time.

Comment: @Rohan Nuckchady.This works well,I didn't thought about that.Actually the orignal question is of vectors.If $(a,b,c) $ lies on Plane $3x+2y+z=7$ then find minimum value of $a^2+b^2+c^2$

Comment: @RohanNuckchady, your comment is timestamped ten minutes earlier than my answer, so there's no way you could have seen it. I was either typing or thinking at the time. If you'd like to expand your comment to an answer, I'll delete mine. Just let me know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a variant of the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality and its name is by a certain community of problem solvers as Titu’s lemma:
$a^2+b^2+c^2 = \dfrac{(3a)^2}{9}+\dfrac{(2b)^2}{4}+\dfrac{c^2}{1} \ge \dfrac{(3a+2b+c)^2}{9+4+1} = \dfrac{49}{14} = \dfrac{7}{2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Also, $$a^2+b^2+c^2=\frac{1}{14}(3^2+2^2+1^2)(a^2+b^2+c^2)\geq\frac{1}{14}(3a+2b+c)^2=3.5.$$
The equality occurs for $$(3,2,1)||(a,b,c),$$ which says that we got a minimal value.

Answer (score 1):

Think geometrically: The equation $3x+2y+z=7$ describes a plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$ with normal vector proportional to $(3,2,1)$. The closest point to the origin is therefore of the form $(a,b,c)=(3r,2r,r)$. From $3a+2b+c=7$ we have $9r+4r+r=7$, so $r=1/2$, and thus $a^2+b^2+c^2=(9+4+1)/4=7/2$.

(Rohan Nuckchady posted this approach as a comment beneath the OP. I either missed it, or was composing my answer when it appeared.)

Answer (score 1):

Let $P(a, b, c)$ be any point on $(\pi): 3 x+2 y+z=7$.[image]$\\\\$

$\\ OP^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2}$ is the minimum iff OP $\perp(\pi) \Leftrightarrow  \displaystyle O P =\left|\frac{3(0)+2(0)+7}{\sqrt{3^{2}+2^{2}+1^{2}}}\right| =\frac{7}{\sqrt{14}} =\sqrt{\frac{7}{2}}$

$\therefore$ the minimun value of $\displaystyle a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \textrm{ is }\frac{7}{2}.$